# Python sorting of string containing number and characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, how can I naturally sort a list of alphanumeric strings such that alpha characters sort ahead of numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184015/in-python-how-can-i-naturally-sort-a-list-of-alphanumeric-strings-such-that-alp)

How do you sort a string containing numbers and characters in python?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @user1742700: after a question of yours is closed, please don't ask a very similar question a few minutes later.  Ask why the question was closed -- in this case, no effort shown and no discussion of obvious questions (should 2 come before or after 17?  what about "A2" vs "A17"? does case matter) -- and try to write a better one.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = '13abc3'
>>> ''.join(sorted(s, key=lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x))
'133abc'
```

This doesn't handle any custom sorting if that is what you're after (this goes number, uppercase, lowercase).