# Python sorting numbered files missing leading zeros

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, file-io, leading-zero

I am reading in a series of **.csv** files which are in the form of:

```
ImageData_999.csv
ImageData_1000.csv
```

As you can see the number increase sequentially but they do not have leading zeros and so when they get read in I am currently looking at a list that ends like this:

```
ImageData_3259
ImageData_3289
ImageData_811
ImageData_907
```

The files do skip around in number so there won't be 3289 files if that is the largest file name but I want to sort them so that they are properly ordered. That is what is below instead of what is above:

```
ImageData_811
ImageData_907
ImageData_3259
ImageData_3289
```

I am working in python and currently just getting the file names from the **os** module like so:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
        yield os.path.join(root, file)
```

I have tried a few methods to sort the list that this produces but none of them seem to change the order.

Comment: This is called a "natural sort" and of course it's been asked before. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: And here's the one I was remembering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184015/in-python-how-can-i-naturally-sort-a-list-of-alphanumeric-strings-such-that-alp

Comment: That worked if you could post it as an answer I could mark this as solved :)

Comment: The usual way is to get it closed as a duplicate. I'll give it my vote right now, it will probably be closed right away.

Comment: I was in the middle of adding this answer, and the question got marked as duplicate.  I think this is simpler:  `sorted(filenames, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]))`

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Ransom posted here is the answer that worked for me:

[Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort them numerically not lexicographically?

Does the filename always start with the same word? "ImageData_"?

If so I would just strip out the letters and then sort them as numbers. (E.g. for each of them `filename = re.sub(r'[^0-9]*', "", filename)`).

And then you can sort them as numbers like this `list1.sort(key=int)` from [How to sort a list numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/numeric-sort-in-python)