# sorting an alphanumeric string in Python- selection sort, bubble sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

The question is
Write a program to sort a string without using built in method.
Input: "a390testai"
output: "039aaiest"

I have looked at some forums to find answer for this. I found this forum [In Python, how can I naturally sort a list of alphanumeric strings such that alpha characters sort ahead of numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184015/in-python-how-can-i-naturally-sort-a-list-of-alphanumeric-strings-such-that-alp) but it does not look like any of the solutions were using selection or bubble sort. **My questions are:**
1) When dealing with such a problem do I have to 1st convert the string to a list? For example: str=list("exam123ple") ? To avoid "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

2) I tried using selection sort and bubble sort but they are not returning intended result.

```
   #Selection sort
s="a390testai"
s=list(s)  # convert to list


for i in range(len(s)):
    min_val=min(s[i:])
    min_val_pos=s.index(min_val)

    s[i],s[min_val_pos]=s[min_val_pos],s[i]

print('s',s)

#Bubble sort
bs="a390testai"

bs=list(bs)
for i in range(0,len(bs)-1):
       if bs[i]>bs[i+1]:
           bs[i], bs[i+1]=bs[i+1],bs[i]

print(bs)

039testaai >> selection sort
390aestait >> bubble sort
```

Thanks in advance for  your help and explanation.

Comment: `str` is already iterable through some implementations make it easier to turn it to a list. I would recommend merge sort.

Comment: bubble sort needs an inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use list as strings are immutable and you can't change parts of them.   Here is an example of bubble sort.

```
s = list('a390testai')

is_sorted = False
while not is_sorted:
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] > s[i+1]:
            s[i+1], s[i] = s[i], s[i+1]
            break
    else:
        is_sorted=True

print("".join(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort needs more than one pass.  Each time through, you go through one less element, since the last one has "bubbled" into place.

In your selection sort, `s.index` returns the index of the *first*  matching item.  So if your string has duplicate letters it returns the wrong one. You need to search inside the `[i:]` range and add `i`, to find the right instance.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, that string had duplicates. Thanks